# Ember #link-to nested routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm calling link-to statement from a template
The Routes are defined like this,

**/app/router.js**

```
Router.map.function(){
    this.route('profiles');
    this.route('exam', function(){
        this.route('create');
        this.route('evaluate');
    });
```

**/app/templates/profiles.hbs**

```
{{#link-to "exam/create"}}
   <p> Create an Exam </p>
{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to "exam/evaluate"}}
   <p> Evaluate Exam </p>
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: This question seems to be missing a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if you have an error or not, but your syntax for the paths is a smidge off

```
{{#link-to "exam.create"}}
   <p> Create an Exam </p>
{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to "exam.evaluate"}}
   <p> Evaluate Exam </p>
{{/link-to}}
```

should use `.` instead of `/`